# How can i get the right length of the string?

Tags: c

Why does my function count more characters than expected?

```
int countLength(char* buffer){
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i=0; buffer[i] != '\n' && buffer[i] != '\0'; i++){
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

For example, if i pass it "Será chuva? Será gente?" as input, it gives 25 instead of 23. why is that?

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try testing: "Sera chuvA? SerA gente?" and give us results

Comment: @SomeName the output was 23

Comment: It's because of that letter "á", obviously. You should check on character-sets, since you can't find "á" in unicode encoding. :)

Comment: Assuming your string is encoded in utf-8, 25 sounds right.

Comment: Why don't you print the index `i` and the character `buffer[i]` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @SomeName so that means i have to somehow decode it?

Comment: One approach would be to convert the string to `char32_t` units and count them

Answer (score 2):

The code gives you the right answer, even if it is not the answer you expect.

The problem is that you expect it to count graphemes (like `á`, while it counts bytes / code-units (`á` consists of two code-units in utf-8 normal form composed).

A first approximation would be to count code-points instead, by skipping continuation-bytes (>0x7f and <0xc0). To actually count graphemes, you would have to use a proper unicode-library with all the character-information like [international components for unicode (ICU)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode), and accept their decisions.

Read up on character-sets, especially [unicode](/questions/tagged/unicode) and the [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) encoding.

<sub>As an aside, `cnt` always mirrors `i`. While an optimizing compiler will remove this duplication, it shouldn't even be there.</sub>

Comment: So how can i bypass this? Is there a way to treat that kind of characters (im Portuguese so there are more characters with that kind of ponctuation) as "normal" ones?

Comment: What are normal ones? If you read up a bit on unicode, you will understand that, despite first impressions to the contrary, plain text is far from plain. Anyway, a badly broken first approximation would be to ignore continuation bytes (>0x7f, but <0xc0).